# Restricting purchases on Product overall quantity not on SKU quantity

Tags: stripe-payments, e-commerce

I want to be able to restrict my orders to a limit on the product quantity and not it's different SKUs.

For instance, say I have a bus route with tickets for each stop. My bus can hold 24 passengers. I want to sell fare on my bus for each of my 24 seats but each stop can be a different price.

I'm having trouble figuring out how to do this in Stripe. 
I am thinking I can try and do a metafield with overall quantity in the product and find a way to check against that before accepting an order?

Comment: Is there a reason you've chosen to use Orders for this and not just Invoices or even just Charges?

Comment: Hmmm I thought I had to use Orders and Products. I actually haven't seen those, I'll give a dive into the docs!

Comment: @korben hmm yeah Invoices and Charges, don't allow me to set limits. I could set my own limits programmatically but I'd rather try and have Stripe's system help me regulate it as much as possible.